# Create a list from object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create a list (keys) from many objects (in this example I will use 3) as this:

```
{Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"}
{Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"}
{Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}
```

And to get as result: `Year,A,B,C,D`. What I need is to keep the value `Year` and combine the rest of the values. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I had done this

```
json = [
    {Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"},
    {Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"},
    {Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}
];
keys= Object.keys(json[0]); // console.log(keys) = Year,A,B
```

I was reading the keys from the first object of my json, but now I need a mix of every object and ther keys

Comment: What, exactly, do you want as an output?

Comment: And what have you done to try and achieve it?

Comment: exactly a string like `Year,key1,key2,evey key but not repeated` like the example: `Year,A,B,C,D`

Comment: So you just want all the keys, and no values? So the output, for example, `["Year", "A", "B", "C", "D"]`?

Comment: Yes, I need the keys separated with commas and my example shows, look my edited

Comment: Your "json" variable is an array, it's not JSON and the array literal isn't valid JSON.

Comment: See `Object.keys` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - use `reduce` and `Object.keys`:

```js
const data = [{
  Year: "2016",
  A: "2.015",
  B: "1.959"
}, {
  Year: "2017",
  A: "1.200",
  C: "2.247"
}, {
  Year: "2018",
  A: "1.301",
  C: "2.056",
  D: "1"
}];

const output = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  Object.keys(val).forEach(key => {
    if (!acc.includes(key)) {
      acc.push(key);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Use `map` and then a `Set` it will remove duplicates for you

Comment: @quirimmo I don't have experience with `Set`, could you edit my answer with your approach to the problem?

Comment: Sorry I just read. I am by phone, I did post an answer but I cannot try it. Feel free to add it as snippet in your edit if it works

Comment: This one works. I added `.join(',')` and got what I need. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` and `Set`

```js
var a=[{Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"},
{Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"},
{Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}]
var arr=[];
a.forEach((e)=>{
arr=[...arr,...Object.keys(e)]
})
arr=[...new Set(arr)]
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Good, but where is Year? I need: Year,A,B,C,D

Comment: Extremely inefficient. Why do you think *Year* will always be the first element in the array? Object properties are unordered, there's no reason to expect their order in an object literal to be maintained (and demonstrable that it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=[{Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"}, {Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"}, {Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}];

console.log([
  ...new Set(a.map(e. => Object.keys(e)).flat())
].join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will generate a `Set` of unique keys. That can then be easily converted back to an array or a string.

```js
const data = [
    {Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"},
    {Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"},
    {Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}
];

const keys = new Set([].concat(...data.map(o => Object.keys(o))));

console.log([...keys]);
console.log([...keys].join(','));
```

<sub>**Note:** the `[].concat[...twoDimensionalArray]` trick can be replaced with a call to [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)—currently browser support is still a bit lacking though.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through every object, take out the keys and add it to a `Set`.

```js
var json = [
    {Year: "2016", A: "2.015", B: "1.959"},
    {Year: "2017", A: "1.200", C: "2.247"},
    {Year: "2018", A: "1.301", C: "2.056", D: "1"}
];

var set = new Set();
json.forEach((value)=> Object.keys(value).forEach(key => { set.add(key); }));
console.log([...set]);
```